# Javascript loaded through angular-cli.json is not accessible on page after navigation

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, loading

I am using a prototype designed in html using custom js, jquery, bootstrap in an angular application. Loaded all the required css and javascript through angular CLI. json. Each page is getting opened well if loaded individually within angular 7 project.
Second stage: Then after , I am configuring the following to to use the prototype in a layout format for an application.

1. Designed a MainLayout [has headerTop, headerNav,and footer included, and a router-outlet for loading other pages which will come from featured modules.]. This MainLayout is loaded within root level router outlet.
2. HmComponent has home page content which is being loaded into MainLayout's router-outlet. And it is being loaded togather with MainLayout. Both MainLayoutComponent and HmComponent have been configured for loading on default root and they are the part of Main module. They are also working fine. At this stage, JS required for home page content and the MainLayout content are available and working well.
3. Now, I navigate to the other pages viz. AboutUsLink   which is a part of featured module and are loaded lazily.

   HomeLink  AboutUsLink  ContactUsLink OtherLink
4. The page is getting loaded well with css, but js required on this page is not available whereas I have already loaded js globally.
5. Lastly, I am coming back on the home page again through HomeLink  from this featured module page AboutUsLink , the home is once again loaded with all the css reuired here; but js is not loaded which were loaded previously while loading the application first time.

   I have added a main router and a public router code for finding anything I did wrong. The router is working well for top level routing as well as featured module routing. I made a cross check of router tree generated through Augury, an add on feature of Chrome.

Remark: At any stage of the navigation, if js is not available, page refreshment make it back and js related stuffs start working well. Seems some overwriting is taking place.

Thanks in advance for commenting or giving a concrete solution of my problem.

Theoretically, such JS loaded in parent should be made available to its children components as this philosophy works for global loading of js.

```
    Both the routers I am using for configuration have been pasted here.
# app.router.ts #

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent,// will be loaded as default.
    children: [
      { path: '', component: HmComponent }, //load home page
      { path: 'hm', redirectTo: '' },

      //Now load its child router module
      { path:"pub",loadChildren:'./public/public.module#PublicModule",data: { preload: true } },
    ]
  },
  { path: 'hm', redirectTo: '' },//redirect to root
];
#  public.module.router.ts #
```

const routes: Routes = [

```
  { path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent },

  { path: 'contactus', component: ContactUsComponent },

  { path: 'listings', component: ProviderSearchComponent },

  { path: 'categories', component: ProviderCategorySearchComponent },

  { path: 'providers', component: ProviderDetailsComponent },

  { path: 'blogdetail', component: BlogdetailComponent },

  { path: 'bloglistings', component: BloglistComponent },

  { path: 'bloggrid', component: BloggridComponent },

  { path: 'loginreg', component: LoginRegFgtPwdComponent },

];
```

Comment: Please try to write a shorter question and describe the problem in a few lines. Not everybody will read all this.

Comment: Will follow it. Thanks for pointing it out. I was trying to make the problem more explicit in nature. Anyway, will follow it. thanks once again.